# A question about Constant sectional curvature between the Riemannian and Kähler manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry

According to the [corollary (3.6)](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=oWLJ6zaSwyIC&pg=PA382&lpg=PA382&dq=%22If%20p%20is%20an%20isotropic%20point%20of%20M%20and%22&source=bl&ots=JK_YQB-0Ac&sig=ACfU3U2_iZsOFgBESxiLoocEkETLata4wQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwikqL6OyLv3AhVjhVYBHVOuBZkQ6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=%22If%20p%20is%20an%20isotropic%20point%20of%20M%20and%22&f=false) on An Introduction to Differentiable Manifolds and Riemannian Geometry,

> **Def**. A Riemannian manifold $M$ is **isotropic** at $p \in M$ if the curvature is the same constant at $k_p$ on every section at $p$.
> And if $M$ is isotropic at every point $p$, then the manifold $M$ is
> called **isotropic**.

> **Corollary 3.6** Let $M$ be a $\underline{Riemannian ~manifold}$ . If $p \in M$ is *isotropic* and every point $p\in M$,  and $(U, \varphi)$ is a coordinate neighborhood
> with coordinate frames $E_1,....E_n$ and Riemannian metric
> $g_{ij}=(E_i,E_j)$, then  $$R_{ijkl}= -k_p(g_{ik}g_{ij}-g_{il}g_{jk})
> $$ at $p\in M$

I think it is better to see the above corollary as :

> **Corollary3.6'** Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold and  $(U, \varphi)$ be a coordinate
> neighborhood  with coordinate frames $E_1,....E_n$ and Riemannian
> metric  $g_{ij}=(E_i,E_j)$. If $p\in M$ is isotropic, then $$R_{ijkl}=
>  -k_p(g_{ik}g_{ij}-g_{il}g_{jk}) $$ at $p\in M$

But, how about the converse statement of **Corollary 3.6(')** ? In other words, if $-{R_{ijkl}}/(g_{ik}g_{ij}-g_{il}g_{jk})$ is constant at each point $p\in M$(or constant whenever pick a point $p \in M$),  then the manifold $M$ is a isotropic. (and naturally, $-{R_{ijkl}}/(g_{ik}g_{ij}-g_{il}g_{jk})=k_p$ )

The main reason I think the converse statement of **Corollary3.6** is just Kähler manifold :
In case of Kähler manifold $M$, there exists a holomorphic sectional curvature at $p \in M$ and also one can think that this curvature is isotropic at $p\in M$ and isotropic (Kähler manifold) as well. However, on the following [PDF](https://math.ecnu.edu.cn/%7Ebliu/files/Complex_manifolds_and_Kaehler_geometry/3.%20Holomorphic%20sectional%20curvature.pdf), the term "isotropic manifold" on the Boothby's textbook seems to correspond "CHSC", short for a space of Constant Holomorphic Sectional Curvature. Anyway, according to **Theorem 1.3.8** on the following [PDF](https://math.ecnu.edu.cn/%7Ebliu/files/Complex_manifolds_and_Kaehler_geometry/3.%20Holomorphic%20sectional%20curvature.pdf),

> **Theorem 1.3.8** The following identities are **equivalent**.
>
> $(1)$ A $\underline{Kähler~ manifold} ~M$ is CHSC with constant $c$;
>
> $(2)$ (mumble, mumble)
>
> $(3)$ For any $U,V,W,X \in T^{(1,0)}M$,
>
> $$R(U,\bar{V},W,\bar{X})=-\frac{c}{2}(g(U,\bar{V})g(W,\bar{X})+g(U,\bar{X})g(W,\bar{V}))$$

is introduced. In this case, however, the converse statement $(3)\Rightarrow (1)$ holds.

To sum up, the statement of **Corollary 3.6** in $\underline{Riemannian~ manifold}$ is nearly analogous to **Thm1.3.8** in $\underline{Kähler~manifold}$ , but why the converse of **Corollary 3.6** does not be mentioned(I doubt that the converse of this corollary would be false), whereas the converse of **Thm1.3.8** holds? Here is the very question I wonder.

Comment: You are right: the converse is the following. If for each $p\in M$, there is $k_p$ such that the sectional curvature of any tangent plane at $p$ is $k_p$, then $R_{ijkl} = k_p(...)$. If moreover $\dim M \geqslant 3$, then $k_p$ is independant from $p$.

This holds for the holomorphic sectional curvature in this way: $(M,g,J)$ has constant holomorphic curvature $k$ if and only if its curvature tensor is $R_{ijkl} = \frac{k}{4}(g_{i\bar{j}} + ....)$ (the formula can be found in Kobayashi Nomizu volume 2, chapter IX)

Comment: The comment is informative, especially the Kobayshi's content, but I am now a little confusing the converse statement of "Riemannian case". I understand that "You are right" means the converse statement of **Cor 3.6** is false. Is it right?

Comment: Then, a counterexample of converse of **Cor3.6** emerges when a manifold whose dimension is equal or grater than $3$, because the the point $p$ does not depend on the point $p$. Is it right?